# Does something remember network state at Linux reboot?

Tags: linux-networking, systemd, keepalived

I have two systems using keepalived with scripts which run at all state transitions (backup, fault, master).  At bootup these scripts document the network configuration (ip addr, ip ro) when they are launched (master state is assumed thus running the master script until determined differently at which time the backup script runs because it is the backup system - I'm testing with it).

What I'm seeing is a route which is only set by the backup keepalived script, I've checked /etc/rc.local (has only 'exit 0"), /etc/network/interfaces and its "source" file and OpenVPN (which, at the point of documentation, isn't running) - none refer to this specific route.  I've looked around under /lib/systemd but haven't found anything either.

This leads me to my question, "Does something remember network state at reboot?", I'm using the reboot command to reboot.  Thanks for any and all help, I'm totally baffled.

Comment: "Linux" is too generic here. What I would do is make sure journal logs survive the reboot (most likely creating `/var/log/journal` directory is enough, but again, depends on which Linux you are running), reboot  and comb through the output of `journalctl --output=verbose --boot=-1` for any clues for what exactly happens at shutdown

Comment: Good point and my apologies - Ubuntu 16.04.